# How to add Gson converterFactory to Apollo Client?

Tags: android, gson, apollo-client

Is it possible to add `Gson` in `ApolloClient`?

According to the doc: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-android#custom-scalar-types.

You can make a `CustomTypeAdapter`. But this makes no sense for `Gson` since the class we convert to is always dynamic.

For example, I want to something like we do in `Retrofit`

```
fun provideApiService(
        okHttpClient: OkHttpClient,
        gson: Gson,
        rxJava2CallAdapterFactory: RxJava2CallAdapterFactory
    ): Retrofit {

        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com")
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .addCallAdapterFactory(rxJava2CallAdapterFactory)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build()

    }
```

Is it possible to add `GsonConverterFactory` in `ApolloClient`? Otherwise I have to manually convert the data into required class objects.

Comment: is this relevent https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-android/issues/55 ?